# iOS: How to sent a UIInterfaceOrientation object via NSNotification

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, nsnotifications

I want to pass a UIInterfaceOrientation object in the userinfo dictionary of an NSNotification. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it inside an NSNumber:

```
id orientationObject = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
[userinfo setObject:orientationObject forKey:@"orientation"];

// pass around ...

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = (UIInterfaceOrientation)[[userinfo objectForKey:@"orientation"] integerValue];
```